# Converting a complicated congruence equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

From:

$$5991x \equiv -289 \pmod{2014}$$

I saw people converted this to:

$$3x \equiv 17 \pmod{2014}$$

But how? My attempt:

$$5991x \equiv -289 \pmod{2014} \equiv 1725$$

$$1997x \equiv 575 \pmod{2014}$$

But that is as far as I can get?

Answer (score 3):

$$5991\equiv-51\pmod{2014}$$

$\implies-51x\equiv-289\pmod{2014}\iff17(3x)\equiv17(17)\ \ \ \  (1)$

$\implies2014|17(3x-17)$

But $(2014,17)=1\implies2014|(3x-17)$

---

Alternatively,  use $\#12$ of [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html) on $(1)$